# How to extract nested tables from HTML?

Tags: python, html, html-table, extract

I have an HTML file (encoded in utf-8). I open it with `codecs.open()`. The file architecture is:

```
<html>
// header
<body>
  // some text
  <table>
    // some rows with cells here
    // some cells contains tables
  </table>
  // maybe some text here
  <table>
    // a form and other stuff
  </table>
  // probably some more text
</body></html>
```

I need to retrieve only first table (discard the one with form). Omit all input before first `<table>` and after corresponding `</table>`. Some cells contains also paragraphs, bolds and scripts. There is no more than one nested table per row of main table.

How can I extract it to get a list of rows, where each elements holds plain (unicode string) cell's data and a list of rows for each nested table? There's no more than 1 level of nesting.

I tried HTMLParse, PyParse and re module, but can't get this working.
I'm quite new to Python.

Comment: 'regex' tag for this question suggests wrong solutions - HTML syntax is not regular, and regexps can give wrong results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

In principle you need to use a real parser (which Beaut. Soup is), regex cannot deal with nested elements, for computer sciencey reasons (finite state machines can't parse context-free grammars, IIRC)

Comment: thanks for the answer. looks like it will solve my problem :)

Comment: I spent a half of night trying to understand B.Soup. and did - it workos for me. thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You may like [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/). I'm not sure I really understood what you want to do with that structure, but maybe this example will help...

```
import lxml.html

def process_row(row):
    for cell in row.xpath('./td'):
       inner_tables = cell.xpath('./table')
       if len(inner_tables) < 1:
           yield cell.text_content()
       else:
           yield [process_table(t) for t in inner_tables]

def process_table(table):
    return [process_row(row) for row in table.xpath('./tr')]

html = lxml.html.parse('test.html')
first_table = html.xpath('//body/table[1]')[0]

data = process_table(first_table))
```

Comment: (months later) just the recipe I need, if I survive http://lsimons.wordpress.com/2008/08/31/how-to-install-lxml-python-module-on-mac-os-105-leopard

Answer (score 2):

If the HTML is well-formed you can parse it into a DOM tree and use XPath to extract the table you want. I usually use [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/index.html) for parsing XML, and [it can parse HTML as well](http://codespeak.net/lxml/parsing.html).

The XPath for pulling out the first table would be "//table[1]".